# Is there any java annotation for adding extra information to a filed?

Tags: java, annotations, metadata

Is there any java annotation for adding extra information to the filed of a class?

I need something like the following example to be accessible at run-time by reflections:

```
public class A
{
   @Description("my field")
   public String name = "";
}
```

Comment: It will if you just write it :-)

Comment: @Thihara How can I write it?

Comment: there is no `java` annotation, you need to implement one and required attributes as per your needs

Comment: @harsh How can I write it?

Comment: I like [the tutorial here](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/java/creating-custom-annotations-and-making-use-of-them/).

Comment: this should help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html

Comment: @chrylis thanks write it as answer to accept it ;)

Comment: You can have a look at the code for the existing annotations and copy that code. They are not very complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not hard to write something like this yourself. For example:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Description {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Then to use it:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Description("my field")
    private String name = "";
}
```

And to get the `value`:

```
Field nameField = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("name");
Description d = nameField.getAnnotation(Description.class);
System.out.println(d.value()); // Prints "my field"
```

**Key pieces:**

- Note that `value` is a special attribute. It doesn't require you to specify the name. If you didn't use `value`, you'd have to do something more like `@Description(desc = "my field")` and reference the name of it directly.
- `default` specifies the default value. It doesn't make much sense here, but it's useful to know. This means you could write `@Description` without a `value` specified and this would be legal. Calling `value()` will return the empty string in this case since that's the default value. If you don't specify a default, then you're required to provide a value.
- `@Target` is used to specify what kind of element(s) the annotation can be used on. In this case, we specified only `FIELD`.
- `@Retention` specifies how long it's kept around and whether or not it can be accessed. `SOURCE` means that it's lost after compiling. This is useful when you only need it for annotation processing. `CLASS` means that it's stored in the bytecode, but you can't access it through reflection. `RUNTIME` is the same as `CLASS`, except you *can* access it through reflection.